# What does this regex do ? groovy

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

i need to understnad what this regex does, but reading the groovy.codehaus docs about regular expressions doesnt seem to help me

```
matches: "[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s-.()_&]+"
```

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

for any hint, thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), which results into `\\p{L}` will match a letter, `\\p{N}` will match a number, `\\s` will match a white space and so on. I'm a bit concerned about `\\s-.` since I'm affraid it will match a range, not sure though...

Comment: @HamZa `\\s-.` will match whitespace, a hyphen or a dot (as it's in a character class)

Comment: @tim_yates Heh, I confirmed it. When I said "range" I meant a range between 2 characters, so let's take a look at [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/cX0xN8) `[\s-.]` It seems indeed that it matches a white space, hyphen or dot. But if we used `[ -.]` it would have matched [way more characters](http://regex101.com/r/rI1rQ5) according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Conclusion: if we use `\s` there will be no range.

Comment: Thanks for the link regexp.reference.unicode.php   -- I can see more clearly now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, all backslashes are escaped, so `[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s-.()_&]+` is to be read as
  `[\p{L}\p{N}\s-.()_&]+`.

`[ ]` is a character class, it matches anything between the two brackets, with the following syntax:

`\p{L}`matches the Unicode property L, letter
`\p{N}` matches the Unicode property N, number
`\s` is any whitespace character
`-.()_&?` don't have special meanings inside character classes, so they can be read literally

So `[\p{L}\p{N}\s-.()_&]` matches any single character of the four mentioned options.
The `+` at the end means "one or more".

Basically, it's the Unicode version of `[a-zA-Z0-9\s-.()_&]+` or shorter `[\w\s-.()&]+`

Comment: +1 It means: _At least one thing and they all must be in the set of letters, numbers, whitespace chars and the chars `-.()_&`_

Comment: hey thank you splitting this, this made me understand it and improve it the way i want to :D cheers